# jqGrid not showing any data

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, json, jqgrid

Im having trouble getting jqGrid to show my data. when i click on the headers, it shows the no records to view a the bottom of the table, but I know that is not the case. the Json I'm trying to display is from a url, and the Json from that url is being pulled from a mysql database using a golang. I am using Jquery jqGrid version 4.4.3.

This is my HTML page with the code to display the table and the function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="jquery/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery/css/jquery-ui.css" />

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
<title>IPAM</title>




</head>
<body>

<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url:'http://localhost:1323/api/v1/leases',
        mtype: "GET",
        datatype: 'jsonString',
        jsonReader:{
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "address",
            },
        colModel: [
            {label: 'address', index:'address', key: true, width: 100},
            {label: 'client_id', name:'client_id', width: 150},
            {label: 'expire', name:'expire', width: 150},
            {label: 'fqdn_fwd', name:'fqdn_fwd', width: 150},
            {label: 'fqdn_rev', name:'fqdn_rev', width: 150},
            {label: 'hostname', name:'hostname', width: 150},
            {label: 'hwaddr', name:'hwaddr', width: 150},
            {label: 'state', name:'state', width: 150},
            {label: 'subnet_id', name:'subnet_id', width: 150},
            {label: 'valid_lifetime', name:'valid_lifetime', width: 150},
        ],
        page: 1,
        scroll: 1,
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 780,
        height: 250,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#jqGridPager"
     });

 });



</script>




</body>
</html>
```

this is the JSON which is pulled from a mysql DB and displayed on the URL I am calling

```
([{"address":"178795010","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:32","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-20009.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800272022E6","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795011","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:58:48","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-18992.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800270FB593","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795012","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:13:55","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"dhcp-client1.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275EA5B9","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795013","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:17","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-10873.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275FCA93","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795018","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:06:16","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-24830.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"080027707E62","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"3232250120","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:15","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob7.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"080027063AD9","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"},{"address":"3232250122","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:22","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob8.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"800027A5E27A","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"}]);
```

Comment: Do you try to use the data **from the same web site**? In the case you should remove `http://localhost:1323` prefix from the URL. The next problem: `datatype: 'jsonString'` is wrong. If you load the data from the server then you should use `datatype: 'json'`. the usage of `scroll: 1` is not recommended, but `loadonce: true` is probably what you need. Another recommendation: don't use retro version 4.4.3, which is not supported since a long time. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which is compatible to 4.4.3. I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid

Comment: See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) the first steps of the usage of free jqGrid. [The wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and readmes to every published version provides additional information.

Comment: @Oleg thank you for the advice, i am now getting this error when loading the page in the browser:    parsererror: Error: jQuery112402678749294365155_1475059615993 was not called 200 success

Comment: hey man Please check now i have fetch data from the url. Thanks !

Comment: @DipakThoke: You are welcome! Why the data starts with `(` and ends with `);`? It seems be your error. The server response should start with `[{` and end with `}]`. By the way `height: "auto"` is better as `height: 250`. You can remove `width: 150` from all `cloModel` items, because it's default value of `width` of columns.

Comment: Hi @Oleg ( and ends with ); this dosn't matter  here you can see the demo.http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/vwb1c0mk/78/.

Comment: @DipakThoke: the usage of `var mydata = ([{...}]);` and the usage of `data:mydata,datatype: "local"` is **not the same** as loading the data from the server via Ajax request (the usage of `url:'http://localhost:1323/api/v1/leases', datatype: 'json'`). You can use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate, which input is correct JSON data.

Comment: @DipakThoke: See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/vwb1c0mk/79/ as an example of loading the data via Ajax by usage of Echo service of jsfiddle (see [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You need set

```
 mtype: "GET",
 datatype: "jsonp",
```

in your jqgrid configuration

Working demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/vwb1c0mk/76/

Comment: @computerNoob Please try to do configuration as shown in the demo.

Comment: if I'm correct, the demo you have kindly given, is to display data that is not from a url, my aim is to get the grid populated with data from the url. Apologies if that was not clear, or if I am missing something from your answer

Comment: you have not configure "colNames".

Comment: colNames: ['address', 'client_id', 'expire', 'fqdn_fwd','fqdn_rev','hostname','hwaddr', 'state','subnet_id','valid_lifetime'],     add this to your jqgrid configuration.

Comment: I understand, i have made the changes, however the grid still does not get populate, by data from the URL.